# How to get gdb call command recognize new line in function return

Tags: gdb

I have the following:

```
$ cat 1.c
#include <stdio.h>

static char buf[1000];

const char*
foo(void)
{
    memcpy(buf, "abc", 3);
    buf[3] = '\n';
    memcpy(buf+ 4, "def", 3);
    buf[7] = '\n';
    buf[8] = 0;

    return buf;
}

int main()
{
    foo();

    printf("%s", buf);

    return 0;
}
```

I compile it: `gcc -g -O0 1.c` and start the gdb: `gdb ./a.out`

I set breakpoint at the line of "printf", then issue call command:

```
(gdb) call foo()
$4 = 0x600980 "abc\ndef\n"
```

You can see that the newline char is not picked up.

I am using this trick to work around it:

```
(gdb) call printf("%s", foo())
abc
def
$5 = 8
```

It works, but kind of cumbersome. I wonder if there is a more succinct way?

If calling printf is the best solution here, is there a way to tell gdb not to show "$5 = 8"?

Answer (score 0):

> You can see that the newline char is not picked up.

On the contrary, you can see *two* newline characters in the buffer (as expected) -- that's what `\n` means.

> I wonder if there is a more succinct way?

The succinct way is what GDB already implements. You appear to want the *verbose* way. Try:

```
(gdb) printf "%s", foo()
```

(Note: this very different from `call printf` that you've already tried.)